# Using MySQL to calculate difference of 2 columns to equal a 3rd column

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Ok so I'm using SQL in phpmyadmin trying to calculate the difference from 2 columns and add that value to a 3rd column. I've imported my data by CSV into the database. I'm trying to "autosum" like excel and Access in SQL database.

My columns are "Tax Collected" - "Tax Paid" = "Tax Gain"

[Imported CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZ0xm.png)

Comment: Just FYI -- storing computed values violates database normalization.  Not sure if that's a concern of yours...

Comment: Understood, when you say storing. Does that mean that you could use virtual or persistent?

Comment: It means that a normalized database does not have a table with values that are computed from other columns. You can get the computed value when you query the table.

Comment: Roger, but can't I have a table of those stored queried values? Separate from the original table though of course

Comment: You **can** ... doesn't mean you **should**.  It depends on whether or not database normalization is important to you.  Perhaps you should do some reading on normalization and under what circumstances you'd want to normalize, and under what circumstances you'd want to violate normalization?

Comment: Gotcha, well thank you so much! You helped me remember something I should keep in mind when structuring this database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That we could proper answer, you should best provide e. g. the table create statement, I assume here that you already defined/added a 3rd column of proper data type and default NULL.

This can IMHO be done with standard SQL command like e. g.

```
   UPDATE 
     YourTableName
   SET 
     TaxGain = TaxCollected - TaxPaid
   WHERE 
     TaxGain IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you! This has been the closest answer to my problem. Now I must confess, I'm pretty green with MySQL.

Where does this comand inputted? As a query? or View?

Comment: Nevermind I found it. Ran it under a query and computed the values in the 3rd column. It worked perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome. Every start in a new language is hard. I propose you to learn standard SQL first like from https://www.w3schools.com/sql/. It helps you to switch to other DBMS like Oracle, Microsoft SQL etc. MySQL specific detail can come later IMHO.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely check it out. I specialize in other areas of IT not databasing. Its a new playground haha. So this was great!